# PowerPivot - Dax Find Text in another Cell - Cannot get string value

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have what is simple data and I want to return the Home or Motor if a find search returns True.

For Example

```
Skills          Type
I Home Sr   
A Mot Pre
```

Type is my custom column

Starting with just returning True and it fails right here with

```
=FIND("Home",[Skills])
```

With

> Calculation error in column 'Table1'[]: The search Text provided to
>   function 'FIND' could not be found in the given text.

Ultimately I want to use If Find is "Home" Return Home if "Motor" return Motor

Desired Output (please note there are other starting variations to the Skills so cannot use a fixed search point in text)

```
  Skills          Type
I Home Sr         Home
A Mot Pre         Motor
```

Comment: It just doesn't seem to see the text of the cell I am referencing

Comment: Any occurrence of `Mot`, `Moto` or `Motor` should produce `Motor` in the `Type` column, right?.

Comment: Yes any match on mot is good or hom for home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following expression for `Type` column:

```
=
IF (
    IFERROR ( SEARCH ( "Mot*", [Skills], 1, 0 ), 0 ),
    "Motor",
    IF ( IFERROR ( SEARCH ( "Hom*", [Skills], 1, 0 ), 0 ), "Home", "Nothing" )
)
```

It will generate Home or Motor for any occurrence of `Hom*` and `Mot*`, note the `*` wildcard

It should produce:

[image]

The screenshot shows the table generated in Power BI, but this solution works in PowerPivot too, I don't have access to PowerPivot in this moment.

> Note if any occurrence is not found it will put `"Nothing"` in your
>   `Type` column so you can replace `"Nothing"` by the string you want to
>   appear in that case.

SEARCH function documentation can be read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634235.aspx).

Let me know if this helps.